# Why does powershell throw a path does not exist error?

Tags: powershell, registry

Why does powershell throw an error when trying to create or modify a registry key from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.2) I used

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\ContosoCompany" -Name "NoOfEmployees" -Value 823
```

The error I get

```
Set-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\Software\ContosoCompany' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\ContosoCompany" -Name "NoOfEmp ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\Software\ContosoCompany:String) [Set-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand
```

I am running the powershell as an admin and I tried to modify existing keys and also tried to create new ones but I still get this error

Comment: are you running these actions as admin?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HKLM is the name of a 'drive'. Move there first

```
Set-Location HKLM:

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\ContosoCompany" -Name "NoOfEmployees" -Value 823
```